# Use slot string in the script tag on Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

What would be the equivalent of this react function in svelte?
I tried to use $$slots but only got boolean values

```
const Foo = ({children}) => {
  console.log(children);

  return(<h1>{children}</h1>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of is the following:

CustomComponent.svelte

```
<script>
  let slotString;
  $: console.log(slotString);
</script>

<div contenteditable="true" bind:innerHTML={slotString}>
  <slot />
</div>
```

index.svelte

```
<script>
  import CustomComponent from "./CustomComponent.svelte";
</script>

<CustomComponent>ABC</CustomComponent>
```

Comment: This receives props through a variable called children, what I want is to pass the string inside the tag
Example:
<CustomComponent>I want to use this text inside the script tag in the CustomComponent</CustomComponent>

Comment: Ok, clear now, see updated anwser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```html
<WrapperComponent>
   <span>This is child content</span>
</WrapperComponent>
```

In React you would get `<span>This is child content</span>` and you would render this as you showed. Given the above construction the Svelte equivalent is: ```html

```

No need to mess around with something called 'children'
Not that in svelte, the children do not have to be in a *tag* you can easily do

```html
<WrapperComponent>
  Free flowing children
</wrapperComponent>
<!-- or also -->
<WrapperComponent>
  <span>one child</span>
  <span>two child</span>
  <span>three child</span>
</WrapperComponent<
```